# Disabled expo plugin and my Deskstop disappeared

Tags: unity, compiz

I have disabled the expo plugin by ignoring the warning but now everything is gone from my desktop. There is no menu on the top or no sidebar. I am using commandline to open firefox and all. And also I have re-enabled expo plugin from ccsm but there is nothing. I also upgraded Ubuntu by using  `sudo apt-get distro-upgrade`  but still there is nothing coming back. please give me the solution ASAP.

Comment: Two things. 1. Check to see if your question has been asked before. 2. Don't use an unfinished title.

Answer (score 1):

Open up ccsm again & enable the unity plugin which was disabled when you removed expo

Comment: It dose not work